Extract text from processed image
I'm trying to extract text from a croped image of any EU license plate. I've tried using easyocr but the results is to inaccurate for me to use. I have trained a YOLOV8 model to  detect the license plate, then I'm croping the image and making some processes on it as grayscale and thresholding. Can anyone help me with the last stage to extract the text from the croped and processed plate? My code currently looks like this
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
from inference import get_model
import easyocr

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])

plate_model = get_model(model_id="plate-recogniser/3", api_key=<API_KEY>)

# Load the image
image_file = r"C:\Users\46723\Desktop\Plate Recognition\samples\swedish.jpg"
image = cv2.imread(image_file)

# Perform inference to detect license plates
results = plate_model.infer(image)[0]

for prediction in results.predictions:
    x_center = prediction.x
    y_center = prediction.y
    width = prediction.width
    height = prediction.height

    # Calculate bounding box coordinates
    x1 = int(x_center - width / 2)
    y1 = int(y_center - height / 2)
    x2 = int(x_center + width / 2)
    y2 = int(y_center + height / 2)

    # Crop the detected license plate area
    license_plate_crop = image[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    
    # Convert to grayscale
    license_plate_crop_gray = cv2.cvtColor(license_plate_crop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    # Adaptive thresholding
    license_plate_crop_thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(
        license_plate_crop_gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, 
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2
    )

    text_results = reader.readtext(license_plate_crop_thresh)
    
    for (bbox, text, prob) in text_results:
        print(f"Detected license plate text: {text} with confidence: {prob:.2f}")

    cv2.imshow("Cropped License Plate", license_plate_crop)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

